# jQuery plugin when using Npm modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm new to Npm packages (coming from Ruby) and trying to load a jQuery plugin that's not necessarily on NPM. I'm building a Chrome extension. The code below is being used in the `content.js` script that's being injected in to the browser. So components like formatting and date pickers are desirable.

At the top of my app file, i have the following:

```
var React = require("react");
var $ = require("jquery");
var moment = require("moment");
```

All works fine, but now I want to add a plugin, and I'm not quite sure where to put it and how to get it accessible to the app. I've tried just loading it like:

```
var React = require("react");
var $ = require("jquery");
require("./jquery-datepicker");
var moment = require("moment");
```

That doesn't work becausae it can't find `$` in the script. So then I tried:

```
require("./jquery-datepicker")($);
```

That didn't work either.

I clearly have no idea what I'm doing, but hoping this is easier than it appears.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you developing client-side code or server-side code?  If you're developing server-side code, what are you trying to do with jQuery and a jQuery date-picker plugin?  You probably need to back up and explain what you're actually trying to accomplish at a higher level.

Comment: Client-side. It's the content.js script for a chrome extension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue and did this:

```
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.$ = window.jQuery;
```

Making $ and jQuery global satisfies plugins that I simply use like this:

```
require('./jquery-datepicker');
```

In all other cases I avoid globals, but in the case of jQuery I think you are going against the grain if you don't. In case you are interested, I use browserify to use node style modules client side.

Comment: window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); if you want to do it in a single line.